# VBA Loop with various criterias

Tags: vba, loops

I have a loop structure as follows:

```
For n = 1 to 10
   If [condition 1] Then
      For i = 1 to 10
         If [condition 2] Then
            [action]
            [EXIT THE INNER LOOP AND START OUTER LOOP with n = 2]
         Elseif [condition 3] Then
            [action 2]
            [EXIT FUNCTION]
         Elseif [condition 4] Then
            [action 3]
            [EXIT BOTH LOOPS]         
         End If
      Next i
   End If
Next n
```

Given the various actions, how should I code properly?

I tried:

```
For n = 1 to 10: Do
   If [condition 1] Then
      For i = 1 to 10
         If [condition 2] Then
            [action]
            GoTo NextIteration
         Elseif [condition 3] Then
            [action 2]
            Exit Function
         Elseif [condition 4] Then
            [action 3]
            Exit Do      
         End If
      Next i
   End If
NextIteration: Next n
Do while negative: Next n
```

I am not sure how I should write the last two lines properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `Exit For` to exit the inner then `IF [Condition 4] Then Exit Loop` right before `Next n` To exit the outer loop at the right conditions

Comment: Another option is to code the interior loop as a `Do While` loop. The looping condition can be something like `i <= 10 And bContinue`. In this case, `bContinue` is a boolean variable that gets set to false when some condition is met.